# How to revert cmap of matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib

I tinkered with the cmap of matplotlib.pylot. Is the change permanent? After commenting my code, the change of cmap still presists. how can I revert it back?

**EDIT**

I solved it, this is a silly problem. Apparently I converted my image into a grayscale image and showed that without the gray cmap. The matplotlib showed the image in color (I though matplotlib was able to detect the color mode).

Answer (score 0):

How did you change it?

Unless you modified your matplotlibrc file, restarting (I)Python interpreter should suffice.

Comment: I changed via code I think . I didn't realize it is permanent.  plt.imshow(responseMap, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral'), vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0). I restarted my IDE(pycharm) but it's still the same

Comment: spectral looks a lot like jet. you should avoid both of them, though.

Comment: Why should I avoid them?

Comment: btw, I have restarted my IDE, I restarted my computer, But it still persists.

Any clue left? I used plt.set_cmap also.

Comment: Show your code and the figure it's generating @DennyDharmawan

Comment: @PaulH Even better, a link to the docs ;) http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html